# SQLite: How to optimize a UNION query

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-optimization

In the UNION query below, subqueries #2 and #4 are identical, and I would like to avoid fetching the same data twice. From what I know, some databases allow you to write a `WITH` clause at the beginning of the query, but SQLite does not support it. So the question is how to optimize the query below.

```
 SELECT disliked, recommended, weight
 FROM
   (SELECT movie_id * 10 AS disliked
      FROM ratings
     WHERE rating IN (1,2)
       AND user_id = #{id}
   ) AS input,
   (SELECT movie_id AS recommended, rating AS weight
      FROM ratings
     WHERE rating IN (4,5)
       AND user_id = #{id}
   ) AS output
 UNION
 SELECT liked, recommended, weight
 FROM
   (SELECT movie_id, movie_id * 10 + 1 AS liked
      FROM ratings
     WHERE rating IN (4,5)
       AND user_id = #{id}
   ) AS input,
   (SELECT movie_id AS recommended, rating AS weight
      FROM ratings
     WHERE rating IN (4,5)
       AND user_id = #{id}
   ) AS output
 WHERE input.movie_id != recommended
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I've read you right this fast, but maybe something like this:

```
 SELECT
     10*r1.movie_id+(r1.rating IN (4,5)) AS likedisliked,
     r2.movie_id AS recommended,
     r2.rating AS weight
 FROM ratings AS r1, ratings AS r2 
 WHERE r1.user_id=#{id} AND r2.user_id=#{id}
       AND r1.rating IN (1,2,4,5) AND r2.rating IN (4,5)
       AND r1.movie_id!=r2.movie_id;
```